# Scraping source code of a website that requires login

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, web-scraping

I created a VB.net form in Visual Studio that takes login details and feeds them to the web browser. The web browser then returns the current URL to a textbox and a <kbd>Get Source</kbd> button takes the URL as an input and displays source in a `RichTextBox`.

The problem is I am able to login to the website, but on viewing source every time I click the <kbd>Get Source</kbd> button, I get **source code** for the login page not the inner pages.

[image: The form i made :]

The code for <kbd>Get Source</kbd> button:

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object,e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim source As String
    source = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(TextBox3.Text)
    RichTextBox1.Text = source
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to help the people who answer your question by posting your code -- particularly the code behind 'Get source' button.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using the page for its intended purpose. But anyway... often when you log into a page it sends back a token which needs to be included in all subsequent calls to the page. Use F12 tools in your browser to inspect the headers in the requests being posted

Comment: Are you sure this is [tag:VBA] and not [tag:vb.net]?  They have similarities but are not interchangeable, and if you're looking for solutions for the wrong language, that could be your first problem.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid please tell what code i could use to store tokens and how to use them to view source

Comment: we have another .Net in the house. This is not VBA.

Comment: sorry it is vb.net

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. You haven't done any investigation to  see if that is _actually_ what is happening. It was an assumption and you need to verify it first. Even then I won't write your code for you.

Comment: This is a rough guide on how to inspect the headers and requests. You need to go through the process in a browser (I suggest chrome) and use this method to see if there is an authorisation present in all requests after your first login.https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art034

Comment: You first navigate to login page with httprequest to get cookies, then you login with POST to get cookies again, then you can get source of the page that requires you to log in. All you need is cookiecontainer, httprequest and 2x get and 2x post requests.

Comment: @CruleD thanx for pointing me in a direction